# Python: Merge two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

Here is my current code:

```
A = {1 : "one", 2 : "two"}
B = {2 : "dva", 3 : "three"}
d = {}

for key in set(list(A.keys()) + list(B.keys())):
    try:
        d.setdefault(key,[]).append(A[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        d.setdefault(key,[]).append(B[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass
print(d)
```

And here is the result I'm currently getting:

```
{1: ['one'], 2: ['two', 'dva'], 3: ['three']}
```

What do I have to do to get a result that looks like the one below?

```
{1 : "one", 2 : ["two", "dva"], 3 : "three"}
```

Comment: Why do you want the second result though? It seems less generalizable/harder to work with.

Comment: Case in point: your task would be much easier if the original `dict`s looked like `{1: ["one"], 2:["two"]}`.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone uses `KeyError` or `if key in my_dictionary`. Use  `my_dict.get("key", "some_default")`, in your case either an empty list (`my_dict.get("key", [])` or something else that makes your task easier.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by first making a new `dict` using the `**` operator:

```py
new_dict = {**A, **B}
>>> new_dict
{1: 'one', 2: 'dva', 3: 'three'}
```

Then a `for` loop over the `set` intersection of keys:

```py
>>> for dupe_key in set(A) & set(B):
...     new_dict[dupe_key] = [A[dupe_key], B[dupe_key]]
...
>>> new_dict
{1: 'one', 2: ['two', 'dva'], 3: 'three'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution:

```
A = {1 : "one", 2 : "two"}
B = {2 : "dva", 3 : "three"}
d = {**A}

for k, v in B.items():
    d[k] = [d[k], v] if k in d else v

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'one', 2: ['two', 'dva'], 3: 'three'}
```

---

Here's a more generalizable solution, that works with an indefinite number of dictionaries:

```
def cool_dict_merge(dicts_list):
    d = {**dicts_list[0]}
    for entry in dicts_list[1:]:
        for k, v in entry.items():
            d[k] = ([d[k], v] if k in d and type(d[k]) != list
                    else [*d[k], v] if k in d
                    else v)
    return d
```

Testing:

```
>>> A = {1: "one", 2: "two"}
>>> B = {2: "dva", 3: "three"}
>>> C = {2: "chewbacca", 3: "ThReE", 4: "four"}
>>> D = {0: "zero", 4: "jack", 5: "five"}
>>> cool_dict_merge([A, B, C, D])
{1: 'one', 2: ['two', 'dva', 'chewbacca'], 3: ['three', 'ThReE'], 4: ['four', 'jack'], 0: 'zero', 5: 'five'}
```

Note that, as others pointed out, the result you're currently getting is probably more preferable in most scenarios, since it's more generalizable and easier to work with. We don't know about your use case though, so just use the method you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

This code achieves what you're looking for:

```py
A = {1 : "one", 2 : "two"}
B = {2 : "dva", 3 : "three"}

d = A.copy()
for key, val in B.items():
    if key in d:
        if isinstance(d[key], list):
            d[key].append(val)
        else:
            d[key] = [d[key], val]
    else:
        d[key] = val

print(d)
```

But, as mentioned in comments, it is less generalizable, meaning you have to check the type of value everytime (more if-else checks) to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I used dictionaries and groupby groups to find like sets of data.  Pandas great for transforming data into dictionaries, tuples, or lists.

```
A = {1 : "one", 2 : "two"}
B = {2 : "dva", 3 : "three"}

z1=zip(A.keys(),A.values())
z2=zip(B.keys(),B.values())

mylist=[]
mylist.append(list(z1))
mylist.append(list(z2))

variables=[]
phrases=[]
for item in mylist:
   for k,v in item:
       variables.append(k)
       phrases.append(v)
df=pd.DataFrame(zip(variables,phrases),columns=['variable','phrase'])

grpDictionary=df.groupby('variable').groups

resultDictionary={}
for key, values in grpDictionary.items():
    resultDictionary[key]=" ".join(df.iloc[values]['phrase'])

print(resultDictionary)
```

output:

```
{1: 'one', 2: 'two dva', 3: 'three'}
```